# Excel # Different Then The Math

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a formula in Excel that reads this:

```
=SUM(B6-F6)/H$1*100%
```

The numbers are as follows:

```
(.2500-.2503)/10*100.
```

When in Excel it comes out to -0.002 but when done by hand it comes out to -0.003. What is the problem with the Excel formula that it is showing a .001 difference?

Comment: when I use those numbers I get -0.003 - are you sure B6, F6 and H1 are exactly .2500, .2503 and 10 respectively? What do you see if you increase the number of decimals in those cells (and increase the decimals for the result cell)?

Comment: @barryhoudini I get the same number but when I am in my Excel sheet with Auto Sum the answer if different. When decimals are added it is -0.0025 and -0.002 respectfully. Very odd how the raw formula will get the correct answer vs. Auto Sum and symbols, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check you format settings for the cell in question.  Excel should show the correct answer for direct calculation as well as your posted formula:

[image]